# Как лучше подключить sqlite3 базу данных для многопоточного использования

Tags: python, sqlite3

Сейчас использую базу данных для бота таким образом:

`bot.py`:

```
import somelib
import sqlite3

client = somelib.Client()

client.login(email=<email>, password=<password>)

sub_client = somelib.SubClient(comId=<comId>, profile=client.profile)

db = sqlite3.connect("databases/chat1.db", check_same_thread=False)
sql = db.cursor()

old = []

class Bot:

    def run(self, chatid):

        commands = Commands()

        title = sub_client.get_chat_thread(chatId=chatid).title

        while True:

            msg = sub_client.get_chat_messages(chatId=chatid, size=3)

            for message, messageId, messageType, author, authorid in zip(msg.content, msg.messageId, msg.type, msg.author, msg.author.userId):

                if messageId in old:
                    pass
                else:
                    print(f"{title} | {author} : {message}")
                    if messageType == 0 and message[0] == "!":

                        if message.lower() == "!help":
                            commands.help(chatid)

                        if message.lower() == "!flip":
                            commands.flip(chatid)

                        if message.lower() == "!top":
                            commands.top(chatid, sql)

                        if message.lower() == "!stats":
                            commands.stats(authorid, author, chatid)

                    old.append(messageId)
```

`main.py`:

```
import concurrent.futures

from lib.bot import Bot

bot = Bot(<email>, <password>)

chatids = ["aa1b9614-61df-4d3a-ac4b-a105ee75283c", "a5dd10aa-551d-41b9-95f6-96fd3bf087dc", "ed2041bf-40f1-465c-a9d9-4fd91164711f", "4496e3ac-1445-4b8b-80a9-b228534474d4", "e3b6c87a-d253-45d5-8718-365451995709", "990619b3-47ab-43ad-9f41-25f380c46e33", "eceed50e-1fda-4a55-923e-e291a6c8ecc2"]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("START")
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        read_chats = [executor.submit(bot.run, chatid) for chatid in chatids]
```

Функционала и применения бд намного больше, в примере выше лишь часть кода для наглядности. Иногда вылетает программа с ошибкой `Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`, судя по всему из-за высокой нагрузки на бд. Как сделать её более устойчивой к многопоточности?

Comment: Использовать вместо sqlite3 какую-нибудь нормальную базу например?

Comment: @andreymal думал над этим, есть рекомендации?

Comment: В качестве учебного проекта sqlite3 вполне сойдёт. По Вашей проблеме - если дело действительно в многопоточном доступе, то смотреть в сторону синхронизации потоков. Из коробки уже есть несколько механизмов для этого: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов а что если сменить бд с sqlite3 на SQLite, или там особой разницы нет?

Comment: @lynx1 Ещё в учебных целях можно попробовать задеплоить это дело на бесплатном pythonanywhere. Этот же хостинг предоставляет бесплатную MySQL.`sqlite3` это и есть питоновская обёртка над `SQLite` :)

Comment: @lynx1, возьмите MariaDB (MySQL) или PostgreSQL - они гораздо более продвинутые и у обеих БД есть бесплатные "community edition" версии

Comment: @MaxU какую легче подключить к ubuntu?

Comment: @lynx1, ту, которую лучше знает доступный и безотказный спец по БД ;)

Answer (score 0):

Про многопоточность:
Замени sqlite3 на многопоточную бд. Пока не поздно.... а то потом будешь как я, искать нужные бд....

Есть ещё вариант, создать файл и там функции со всеми операциями к бд. таким образом будет лишь 1 поток к бд....

Про оптимизацию:
способы оптимизации бд лично мне не известны